# error con hash bcryptjs

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy haciendo la autenticación para iniciar sesión y al momento de ingresar me marca erro con bcryptjs

mi código

```
// autenticacion
app.post('/auth', async (req, res)=>{
    const user = req.body.user
    const pass = req.body.pass
    let passwordHaash = await bcryptjs.hash(pass, 8);
    if (user && pass){
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE correo = ?', [user], async (error, results)=>{
            if (results.length == 0 || !(await bcryptjs.compare(pass, results[0].pass))) {
                res.send('Usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta');
            } else {
                res.send('Ha iniciado sesion correctamente');
            }
        })
    }
})
```

y este es el error que me muestra al tratar de iniciar sesión
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realmente no se porque me arroja error, no se que estoy colocando mal

Answer (score 0):

Hola John a pesar de que ya ha pasado bastante tiempo caí en tu consulta y paso a responderla por si a alguien más le sirve.

El problema que tienes está en esta linea

`let passwordHaash = await bcryptjs.hash(pass, 8);`

Estas intentando hacer un Hash con una función Async pero no le brindas los parámetros necesarios. En tu caso yo te recomendaría hacerlo de esta manera

```
let passwordHash = bryptjs.hashSync(pass, 8)
```

O en su defecto si seguís con la intención de que sea asíncrona usar

```
bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
bcrypt.hash(pass, salt, function(err, hash) {
    let passwordHash = hash;
});
});
```

Comment: Si te fijas, la última línea del error le indica que éste ocurre en el método `compare`, y supongo que  puede explicarse por la inexistencia de un campo `pass`

Comment: El campo PASS lo ha determinado en su código y es igual al REQ.BODY.PASS eso creo que está bien ya que lo va a recibir como un Request de su client.

Comment: y si el campo se llama "password", no crees que llegaríamos justo a ese mismo error?